# Xcode 9 Beta Use of undeclared type 'SKError'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storekit, xcode9-beta

I just tried to build my project in **Xcode 9 beta** and I'm getting an error that says:

> Use of undeclared type `SKError`

This error is in a CocoaPod called **[SwiftyStoreKit](https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit)**.

I tried cleaning the project with no success.

Any ideas on how to fix this? I didn't hear anything about changes to `SKError` in Xcode 9, iOS 11, or Swift 4. Although I haven't converted my project to Swift 4 yet. Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe try `SKError.Code` or `SKErrorCode`...

Comment: @l'L'l How would that work? I’m using a CocoaPod called SwiftyStoreKit. So not sure really how to edit it.

Comment: The developer would need to make the changes to the framework/library, or you perhaps. Changing it to `SKErrorCode` might not even be the solution to the problem as a whole perhaps. Generally you'll see undeclared type errors though when trying use beta SDKs, as things haven't been fully implemented and/or older SDK has something while the newer does not.

Comment: Another thing you could do is globally `var SKError = SKErrorCode()`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit/issues/225) in the **SwiftyStoreKit** framework. As a quick fix, trying switching to the `swift-4.0` branch instead:

```
pod 'SwiftyStoreKit', :git => 'https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit', :branch => 'swift-4.0'
```

edit your `Podfile`, with the line above, then run `pod install` again.

By the way, according to the aforementioned issue, this looks like a bug on Apple's side ;(

Comment: Do you know if that branch is still compatible with previous versions of iOS and Xcode?

Comment: @CharlieFish Quickly browsing this [branch commits](https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit/compare/swift-4.0) it doesn't look compatible at all ;( Anyway, you can always go back-and-forward between the pods depending on your current setup...

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I'll just use Xcode 8.3.3 until this gets fixed.

Comment: For anyone curious. This seems to still be an issue in beta 2.

Comment: Beta 5 and getting 22 errors inside Storekit. Tried - pod 'SwiftyStoreKit', :git => 'https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit', :branch => 'swift-4.0' but got:  warning: Could not find remote branch swift-4.0 to clone.

Comment: XCode Version 9.0 beta 6 (9M214v) still produces the same SKErrorCode compiler error.